# mysql select a different field is a field is null

Tags: mysql

I have a staff table

```
id  int(11) 
names   varchar(120)
family_names    varchar(100)
nickname    varchar(100)
```

and a table of who is at work

```
  id    int(11)
  personid int(11)
  titleid    int(11)
  typeid    int(11)
  at_work   datetime
  status int(11)
```

My problem is that I need to produce a report where I check who is at work and display names, family name and title. As people are called by nickname, I need to check first if nickname exist so I find this example on this site

```
SELECT IF(LENGTH(nickname)>0, nickname, names) FROM staff_list
```

I will get either the nickname or the names, but it do not solve my request as I need to search mu who_is_at_work table and then get the staff at work and create that list.

Is it possible to do a select within a select to get the three fields that I need

nickname/names, family name, title

After a while I figured out how to do it.

I found the solution, thanks for posting. Here is what I ended up doing.

```
SELECT p.id AS ID, 
   IF(LENGTH(p.nickname)>0, p.nickname, p.names) AS 'Names/Nickname',
   p.family_names AS 'Family name', 
   r.rank AS 'Rank'
   FROM atworklist AS who
   LEFT JOIN stafflist as p on p.id = who.personid   
   LEFT JOIN title AS r ON r.id = p.titleid
   where who.shipid= 2 and who.status in (2,3)
   ORDER BY r.sortorder
```

Works like a charm for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the null values you can use coalesce.

```
select coalesce(nickname, names) from staff_list
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

If you want to check for empty strings you can do it this way:

```
 select case when nickname = '' then names else nickname end from staff_list
```